# How to access all columns one by one of a 3D numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

```
Y=np.array([[[2,4,6],[3,5,7],[2,5,9]],[[7,3,2],[3,4,5],[1,4,7]]])

for k in range(2):
    print(Y[:,:,k])
```

If we consider a 3D array Y and start to access all the 6 columns one by one using only one variable for accessing columns how can we do that using python?

If we want to perform similar work in MATLAB we can use the given syntax to access columns one by one at each iteration

```
Y(:,k)
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop you have will print 2d slices at depth of k. If I understand your question correctly, you want 1d slices at every j and k.

If you only want 1 loop, you will need to flatten Y on the 3rd axis and then iterate through that:

```
Y.shape = 3, 6
for j in range(Y.shape[1]):
    print(Y[:, j])
```